# MySQL error on form submit

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

UPDATE:

Thank you all so much for your help on this. I've taken a different tack and decided
to use just one table.

---

I have a database set up consisting of 3 tables. I have three short forms and I want to use the same add_player.php to write the form data to the database.

Depending on which form is submitted (I have a hidden field defining form_id in each form), data would get written to one of three tables: ff_offense, ff_kicker, ff_defense.

I am getting an unexpected } error. I know my syntax is off, but I'm not well versed enough in PHP to be able to spot the culprit. Here is the code of add_player.php:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","dariia","celtic03");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("football", $con);

if($form_id ="offense") {$query="INSERT INTO ff_offense (ID, PLAYER, POSITION, TEAM, PASS_YDS, RUSH_YDS, REC_YDS, RECEPTIONS, TD) 
    VALUES ('NULL','$_POST[PLAYER]','$_POST[POSITION]','$_POST[TEAM]','$_POST[PASS_YDS]','$_POST[RUSH_YDS]','$_POST[REC_YDS]','$_POST[RECEPTIONS]','$_POST[TD]')"}

    elseif($form_id="kicker") {$query="INSERT INTO ff_kicker {K_ID, K_PLAYER, K_TEAM, K_EXTRA_PTS, K_FG)
        VALUES ('NULL','$_POST[K_PLAYER]','$_POST[K_TEAM]','$_POST[K_EXTRA_PTS]','$_POST[K_FG]')"}

    elseif($form_id="defense")  { $query= "INSERT INTO ff_defense {D_ID, D_TEAM, D_SACKS, D_INT, D_TD}
        VALUES ('NULL','$_POST[D_TEAM]','$_POST[D_SACKS]','$_POST[D_INT]','$_POST[D_TD]')"} ;

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();   

if (!mysql_query($query,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The error was for line 11, which would be VALUES line for `if($form_id="offense")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are missing some semi-colons after your strings as well.

```
if($form_id == "offense") {
    $query="INSERT INTO ff_offense (ID, PLAYER, POSITION, TEAM, PASS_YDS, RUSH_YDS, REC_YDS, RECEPTIONS, TD) 
    VALUES ('NULL','$_POST[PLAYER]','$_POST[POSITION]','$_POST[TEAM]','$_POST[PASS_YDS]','$_POST[RUSH_YDS]','$_POST[REC_YDS]','$_POST[RECEPTIONS]','$_POST[TD]')";
} elseif($form_id=="kicker") {
    $query="INSERT INTO ff_kicker {K_ID, K_PLAYER, K_TEAM, K_EXTRA_PTS, K_FG)
        VALUES ('NULL','$_POST[K_PLAYER]','$_POST[K_TEAM]','$_POST[K_EXTRA_PTS]','$_POST[K_FG]')";
} elseif($form_id=="defense")  { 
    $query= "INSERT INTO ff_defense {D_ID, D_TEAM, D_SACKS, D_INT, D_TD}
        VALUES ('NULL','$_POST[D_TEAM]','$_POST[D_SACKS]','$_POST[D_INT]','$_POST[D_TD]')";
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting another error :) It reads:
 
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setQuery() on a non-object in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\kickass\\add_player.php on line 21
 
Line 21 is this: $db->setQuery($query);
 
GAH!

Comment: Try commenting out`$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();` and running your script again if that solves it you don't need those two lines.

Comment: The $query variable was empty?

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**

You're using curly braces instead of parenthesis in your queries.

```
 $query="INSERT INTO ff_kicker {K_ID, K_PLAYER, K_TEAM, K_EXTRA_PTS, K_FG)
```

should be

```
 $query="INSERT INTO ff_kicker (K_ID, K_PLAYER, K_TEAM, K_EXTRA_PTS, K_FG)
```

You did it multiple times so check all of your queries for this error.

**OLD ANSWER**

You should be using the comparison operator (`==` or `===`) instead of the assignment operator:

```
if($form_id="offense")
```

should be

```
if($form_id==="offense")
```

Two points to note:

1. You are wide open to SQL injections
2. mysql_* is going to be depracated. You should switch to [mysqli_*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Ha, I didn't notice that, only looked at the guts of the first query. He's also missing semicolons for all of them :]

Answer (score 4):

```
if($form_id="offense").
```

Should be

```
 if($form_id=="offense")
```

Also, you are wide open to SQL injection, make sure you sanitize your input. Even if you do sanitize your input I would advice you to start using PDO, which is much safer!

Comment: It wasn't me, but maybe because they're not answers? The syntax is valid even if the logic is flawed. The question was about a specific syntax error, which is solved with semicolons, not fixing equalities

Comment: Maybe so, still that would mean this awnser and John Conde's awnser are "not useful", which imo it is. And I know, I upvoted yours ;)

Comment: I agree, but I find it hard to upvote an answer that doesn't address the specific error the OP pasted. My downvotes are reserved for the answers that are completely wrong :]

Comment: @orourkek that's not a problem =D

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test if a variable is equal to a value, you have to use the [**comparison operator**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), which is **`==`**

Here, you are using the [**assignment operator**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), which is **`=`** -- it take the value you write on its right, and put it inside the variable you've written on its left.

Basically, you should update your three conditions, so they look like this :

```
if($form_id == "offense")
elseif($form_id == "kicker")
elseif($form_id == "defense")
```

Comment: This only addresses the logic flaw, not the two syntax errors

Answer (score 2):

assignment operator is `=`

checking condition is `==`

and when we want to check data type as well we use `===`

so you got problem in your condition it should be like below

```
if(variable == 'string'){
    // logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These other answers are right, but there's a missing semicolon at the end of this declaration also, which is what's causing the syntax error:

```
if($form_id ="offense") { $query="INSERT INTO ff_offense (ID, PLAYER, POSITION, TEAM, PASS_YDS, RUSH_YDS, REC_YDS, RECEPTIONS, TD) 
    VALUES ('NULL','$_POST[PLAYER]','$_POST[POSITION]','$_POST[TEAM]','$_POST[PASS_YDS]','$_POST[RUSH_YDS]','$_POST[REC_YDS]','$_POST[RECEPTIONS]','$_POST[TD]')"; }
```

edit: To be clear, all of the declarations are missing a semicolon, not just the one.

Comment: That's technically valid syntax, and is not what's causing the error to be thrown

Comment: if you write an answer and see `sql injection` vulnerability, you should mention it. same as here. It's not hard to add just 1 more `=` the above code, is it?

Comment: Well considering the number of answers on the page that only corrected the equality, this answer was just an addition to those. No one seems to notice the semicolons, which is what would cause the error he pasted. Hence why I started with "these other answers are right"